# Firefox: Promise.then not called asynchronously

Tags: javascript, firefox, promise

I read the Promise/A+ specification and it says under 2.2.4:

> onFulfilled or onRejected must not be called until the execution context stack contains only platform code

But in Firefox (I tested 38.2.1 ESR and 40.0.3) the following script executes the onFulfilled method synchronously:

```
var p = Promise.resolve("Second");
p.then(alert);
alert("First");
```

(It does not seem to run using alerts here, it can also be tried here: http://jsbin.com/yovemaweye/1/edit?js,output)

It works as expected in other browsers or when using the ES6Promise-Polyfill.

Did I miss something here? I always though that one of the points of the then-method is to ensure asynchronous execution.

**Edit:**

It works when using console.log, see answer by Benjamin Gruenbaum:

```
function output(sMessage) {
  console.log(sMessage);
}

var p = Promise.resolve("Second");
p.then(output);

output("First");
```

As he points out in the comments, this also happens when using synchronous requests, which is exactly why it happens in your test scenario.
I created a minimal example of what happens in our Tests:

```js
function request(bAsync) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
      if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        resolve(xhr.responseText);
      }
    });
    xhr.open("GET", "https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/resources/sap-ui-core.js", !!bAsync);
    xhr.send();
  });
}

function output(sMessage, bError) {
  var oMessage = document.createElement("div");
  if (bError) {
    oMessage.style.color = "red";
  }
  oMessage.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sMessage));
  document.body.appendChild(oMessage);
}

var sSyncData = null;
var sAsyncData = null;

request(true).then(function(sData) {
  sAsyncData = sData;
  output("Async data received");
});

request(false).then(function(sData) {
  sSyncData = sData;
  output("Sync data received");
});


// Tests
if (sSyncData === null) {
  output("Sync data as expected");
} else {
  output("Unexpected sync data", true);
}
if (sAsyncData === null) {
  output("Async data as expected");
} else {
  output("Unexpected async data", true);
}
```

In Firefox this leads to:

[image]

Comment: Returning `"Second"` , `"First"` , `"Third"` at firefox ?

Comment: Exactly, it should be "First", "Second", "Third" as in Chrome - or am I missing something?

Comment: Want to share with you this article: https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/

Comment: You can ignore the setTimeout - I don't care if that is second or third (maybe I should have left it out) - I am just concerned with "First" and "Second" being in the wrong order.

Comment: Please paste the code that demonstrates the issue into your question so this question stays relevant when outside links have long since been changed or died.

Comment: You are right @jfriend00 - I am just so used to create snippets to be sent around via URL, I forgot stackoverflow has this feature. I added further examples.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### This is because you're using `alert`

When you use `alert` here it blocks and all bets are off - the page has frozen, execution halted and things are at "platform level".

It might be considered a bug, and it's certainly not what I would expect - but at the core this is about the incompatibility between `alert` and JavaScript task/microtask semantics.

If you change that alert to a `console.log` or appending to `document.innerHTML` you'd get the result you expect.

```js
var alert = function(arg) { // no longer a magical and blocking operation
  document.body.innerHTML += "<br/>" + arg;
}

// this code outputs "First, Second, Third" in all the browsers.

setTimeout(alert.bind(null, "Third"), 0);

var p = Promise.resolve("Second");
p.then(alert);

alert("First");
```

From what I can tell, this is actually [permitted optional behavior](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/webappapis.html#dom-alert):

> **Optionally**, pause while waiting for the user to acknowledge the message.

(Emphasis mine)

#### Basically, what firefox does is this:

- Execute until it encounters the first `alert`.
- Run any microtasks to completion before pausing (tasks are paused, and not microtasks).
- The `then` is run as a microtask, so "Second" gets queued and precedes the `alert`.
- The `Second` alert gets run.
- The `First` alert gets run.

Confusing, but allowed from what I can tell.

Comment: I don't get it - you seem to be right. But I just created the minimal example with alert because we found this behavior in code that does not use alerts at all... I will try to create a better minimal example. If I do not manage to create a minimal example or find the problem elsewhere, I will mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: @sirion this isn't about `alert` in particular, this is about running all microtasks to completion when pausing the event loop until a task completes. There are other cases that can trigger it (like synchronous ajax for example).

Comment: Synchronous ajax is a good hint - I think I saw that somewhere in the surrounding code.

Comment: I _suspect_ this introduced it: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1094248 , the issue is discussed there and it's an interesting read.

Comment: `alert` (or something else) synchronously running microtasks seems to be the unexpected thing here. Technically A+ forbids processing the queue from user code (which `alert()` surely is), but I'm fine with any behaviour as long as the callback is executed after `.then()` returns. Firing the queue should be a bit more explicit though :-)

Comment: @Bergi what happens here is the first `alert` pauses the event loop so no further tasks can run, but microtasks still run - where or not this is desirable behavior is another issue. In any case Promises/A+ is not really relevant here, the actual ES specification and the DOM API have to be a lot more specific than "platform code" :) See the bugzilla issue for more details.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Right, pretty interesting discussion there… and horrible synchronous waiting examples, people manually firing the event queue from js code and other scary stuff…